# Changed the mod for ~/.. directory by mistake, made it 744, can't boot anymore

Tags: macos, terminal, startup, permission

I ran the following command by mistake:

```
sudo chmod 744 ~/..
```

and I can't boot my macbook anymore, it freezes with the brown screen and ajax-style spin. What should I do to make it work normally again?

I tried:

a) Disk utility (repair permissions) - didn't help
b) resetpassword -> reset ACL and permissions for home directory - didn't help.

I booted in the recovery mode, opened the terminal and went to "/Volumes/Macintosh HD". Yes, this was the disk (or should I say "path") I changed the permissions for.

How do I restore them now? And what are they were?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to restore it by going to the terminal in recovery mode and performing:

```
chmod 777 "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/"
```

But I believe that `777` is too much. What's the default umask for `~/..` ?

**UPDATE2:**

I don't know why it worked since `~/..` means `/Users`, not `/`.

Comment: It's on my machine:
`drwxr-xr-x    8 root       admin         272 27 lut 14:53 ..`

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek, and what's the umask for that?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Really? No ACLs?

Comment: that's my output from `ls -la` inside $HOME how to check umask ?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek, it can be calculated from "drwxr-xr-x", let me check.

Comment: @njboot, positive? not 755?

Answer (score 2):

I would do two things to restore a Mac in this situation.

1. boot to recovery mode and run Disk Utility - repair the drive, the volume and then repair permissions.
2. Boot to recovery mode and run the installer. That should fix or log the exact directory that has improper ACL/permissions and re-create all basic mount points.

The installer log can be read in recovery mode boot if step 2 doesn't fix things and we can perhaps refine exactly what directory or directories are now messed up. There is a chance that you had a separate failure and your `chmod` was coincidental to the issue as opposed to causative.